# How to generate random numbers with GoogleRefine or OpenRefine in GREL?

Tags: random, openrefine, google-refine, grel

I'd like to generate random numbers in GREL. Is there any way to do this? I'd like to use a GREL phrase like:

"http://example.org/id/" + random + ".html"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GREL has not `random` function, but you can use Python/Jython instead :

```
import random

# return a random integer between 0 and 1000
return value + str(random.randint(0, 1000)) + ".html"
```

**Example :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ostephens on twitter shared a similar solution meanwhile:

import random

return random.randint(1,9)

Source: https://twitter.com/hauschke/status/839110740795666433

Comment: Owen is the best user of Open refine I know, and I'm proud to have been faster this time. ^^